# Are 868 MHz and 915 MHz antennas interchangeable?

Tags: rf, antenna

In the context of RF communication for 10-20 km range, I see some antennas sold as 868 MHz, some sold as 915 MHz, and some sold with a broad range like "850-950".  The latter seems to imply that some antennas can be used for both frequencies.

How precise is the actual antenna?

Comment: My guess is  you'd have to see what the bandwidth of the antenna is and see if the passband overlaps

Comment: Unless it's a narrowly tuned type, such as as a *narrow-band* Yagi, it will likely make little difference. See https://www.aeronetworks.ca/2020/02/yagi-antenna-for-900-mhz-ism-band.html for designing your own.

Comment: 10% bandwidth for an antenna is easily achieved.  So if an antenna is designed for 900 MHz, it's almost certainly has decent performance at 850 MHz and 950 MHz.

Comment: How long is a rope? Check the datasheet. If there exists no datasheet then don't buy the product. Also you _can't_ get 10-20km range on the 868MHz band since it's restricted to 25mW ERP. Also, what kind of tower did you intend to place the antenna in?

Comment: @Lundin You can get 10-20km range on 868mhz with LoRa

Comment: @CaptainCodeman I very much doubt that even in ideal conditions. Again: you are restricted to 25mW. And you'd also be restricted to 1% duty cycle if using Lora.

Answer (score 4):

> How precise is the actual antenna?

It depends on the individual antenna. It's quite possible to have a design that covers only a single band, or a design that covers both bands. You'll need to check the data sheet for the specific antenna you wish to use (or measure it). If an antenna is described as being suitable for just one of those bands you shouldn't assume it will work adequately on the other one.

The bandwidth (operating frequency range) is one of a set of parameters that can be traded off against each other as part of the antenna design process. So the designer might choose to cover both bands at the cost of a lower gain, or a single band with higher gain for a given number of antenna elements. Or they might choose a design with more antenna elements giving higher gain across both bands at the cost of more complexity and hence a higher price.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it depends on the antenna design, and even more so at what performance is considered as acceptable by the manufacturer. Every antenna (except truely wideband ones such as a Discone, which however is low gain) have a sweet spot frequency for best performance. Then there is bandwidth, which essentially how far you can diviate from the sweet spot and still get an adequate performance. While designing an antenna, there is a tradeoff between wide bandwith and a peak performance at the central frequency.

Generally speaking, an antenna designed for 868mhz specifically, all other variables equal, should outperform the dual band one, however will have inadequate performance on 915mhz (and vise versa)

Another important point! Many cheap antennas i have tested are in fact tuned to a wrong frequency! I had one for 915mhz for lora, which are actually centered around 868mhz, and an 868 one was way out of band. If you plan doing any more antenna stuff, get a NanoVNA! It is amazing on measuring and tuning antenna performance. Otherwise just buy the expensive antennas so you can trust the numbers they put on the package.

Lastly, for such long range communication especially with low power devices, you should consider a directional antenna, which in contrast with the omnidirectional, will focus all the energy in one direction greatly improving range at the cost of a need to be pointed in the right direction.

Hope that helps, and Happy hacking :)